# Django big file transfers

Tags: django, http, cdn, scribd

I am looking for a django app that can help smooth the process of uploading big size documents by using HTTP Post.

Documents ranging anything from 150mb to 500mb.

I wrote a small library that handles PDF uploads and parses it to my scribd library and through that embed it onto my site.

Currently my model is quite simple, it takes a `FileField`, preferably PDF and just and uploads the PDF File, through that makes use of the scribd library and send it directly to scribd for encoding.

The problem is, somewhere along the actual upload process, it times out, no errors in the log, I have adjusted my django apps size for files, Apache's size for files, and I am a bit lost at the moment not knowing where to go from here.

Although I want to eliminate the manual work, so ideally I'd still like to use it through my site.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit too late, but, have you tried [django-bft](https://github.com/django-bft/django-bft)